# How to build a custom share sheet in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying build a custom sharesheet in react-native like how spotify or locket does it (I assume this is a custom sharesheet). I was wondering how you can build a custom one where I only show iMessage and instagram and change the styles. I noticed the react-native-share-sheet and the Share from react native doesn't let you customize it so I was wondering if this is possible to build in react-native?

Also building the "share sheet" from scratch would not work since there is no way to pop up the iMessage. (Linking("sms://) opens a new app)

Exmaple for spotify:

[image]

Example for locket:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!